# Перенос хранимых процедур из dev в prod базу данных

Tags: php, sql-server, миграция, procedure

Интересуют подходы и инструменты для синхронизации хранимых процедур из тестовой базы данных в продакшн. Разрабатываю на PHP, может существуют какие то готовые пакеты для миграций с возможностью отката на предыдущее состояние. Подскажите как вы производите миграции? База MSSQL

Answer (score 0):

Database проект в VS, студия генерирует скрипт для публикации проекта на сервер.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833165(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать еще несколько вариантов в том числе и гибридный.
Например Database Project в VS умеет делать DacPac или это можно делать через SSIS/DacFX фреймворк.

Вы можете сделать репликацию.
Вы можете использовать специальное задание и Linked Server.
Вы можете использовать задание для бекапирования и задание на другом сервере для развертывания.